# How can I get the location of picture in a xlsx file by using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I can get the picture file, but I don't konw how to get the location of picture.
I can't find the correct method in POI.

```
    InputStream is= new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");  
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);  

    List<PictureData> list = (List)workbook.getAllPictures();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(list.size());
    for(Iterator<PictureData> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
        PictureData pd = it.next();
        savePic(i, pd);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to get the position information from XSSFSheet.

```
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch(); // I know it is ugly, actually you get the actual instance here
        for (XSSFShape shape : drawing.getShapes()) {
            if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
                XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
                XSSFPictureData xssfPictureData = picture.getPictureData();
                ClientAnchor anchor = picture.getPreferredSize();
                int row1 = anchor.getRow1();
                int row2 = anchor.getRow2();
                int col1 = anchor.getCol1();
                int col2 = anchor.getCol2();
                System.out.println("Row1: " + row1 + " Row2: " + row2);
                System.out.println("Column1: " + col1 + " Column2: " + col2);
                // Saving the file
                String ext = xssfPictureData.suggestFileExtension();                
                byte[] data = xssfPictureData.getData();
                String filePath = "C:\\..\\Images\\" + xssfPictureData.getPackagePart().getPartName();
                try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
                    os.write(data);
                    os.flush();         
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how getAllPictures() is implemented: Query the XSSFSheet (inSheet) with getRelations() and look for XSSFDrawing.

The CTDrawing class provides several methods to get the anchor of the pictures.

```
for(POIXMLDocumentPart dr : inSheet.getRelations()) {
    if(dr instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
        CTDrawing ctDrawing = ((XSSFDrawing) dr).getCTDrawing();
        for (CTTwoCellAnchor anchor: ctDrawing.getTwoCellAnchorList()) {
            CTMarker from = anchor.getFrom();
            int row1 = from.getRow();
            int col1 = from.getCol();

            CTMarker to = anchor.getTo();
            int row2 = to.getRow();
            int col2 = to.getCol();

            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```